# How to remove Null plot markers in QuantilePlot?

Tags: plotting, bugs, marker

**Bug introduced in 12.0 and persisting in 13.2.0**

I want to change the plot markers of the data points in `QuantilePlot`. This seems pretty straightforward:

```
QuantilePlot[
 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 32], NormalDistribution[mu, sigma],
 ReferenceLineStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashing[{Large}]], PlotMarkers -> {"○"}]
```

However we can see that we get a "Null" plot marker at either end of the reference line:
[image]

Is there a specific command required in `QuantilePlot` to customise the plot markers for the data points?

Comment: Please submit a bug report to Wolfram Tech Support

Comment: @kglr 12.2 is not released yet.

Comment: @Szabolcs, on Wolfram cloud `$Version` returns  _"12.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (November 16, 2020) "_. Rolled back the edit.

Comment: @kglr Interesting, didn't know they released it a month ago in the cloud ...

Comment: Shorter code that has the problem is:  QuantilePlot[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 32], 
 PlotMarkers -> {"o"}]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like a bug.

A work-around: Post-process to remove the unwanted `Null`s:

```
{mu, sigma} = {1, 2};

SeedRandom[1]

qp = QuantilePlot[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 32], 
 NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], 
 ReferenceLineStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashing[{Large}]], 
 PlotMarkers -> {"○"}];

qp/. Inset[Style[Null,___],___] -> {}
```

[image]

**Note:** The issue does not arise in Version 11.3.0.

Comment: Thanks for the work around.

Comment: Interesting that the problem isn't present in 11.3.0, I'm using 12.1.1.0.

Comment: The bug exists in 12.3 as well.