# Null using PlotMarkers in QuantilePlot

Tags: bugs

I suspect a bug using PlotMarkers and QuantilePlot. Seems related to the unity line, see figure below.

```
QuantilePlot[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100], 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: duplicate? : [How to remove Null plot markers in QuantilePlot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/233816/125)

Comment: Oh, thanks! Sorry